# Powershell Remove-Item leaving Folders Behind

Tags: powershell

So I want to clean up some of my users profiles on a nightly basis using the following "script"

```
Get-ChildItem 'F:\View\Profiles\' -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object {$_.Directory -match 'F:\\View\\Profiles\\((\w*).V2)\\AppData\\Roaming\\Trillian\\users\\((\w*%\w*%\w*))\\logs\\(_CLOUD|ASTRA)'} |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

This deletes all the log files but leaves behind the folder structure. Because of that I tried the following query.

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\TestProfileClean' -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object {(($_.Name -eq "logs" -and $_.Directory) -and $_.DirectoryName -match 'C:\\TestProfileClean\\(\w*.V2)\\AppData\\Roaming\\Trillian\\Users\\((\w*)%40(\w*)%2Ecom)' )} |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

This ensures that the folder deleted is named "logs" it is a directory and the directory name is in this format.

```
C:\\TestProfileClean\\(\w*.V2)\\AppData\\Roaming\\Trillian\\Users\\((\w*)%40(\w*)%2Ecom)
```

The problem is when I run the second command it does not delete any files, if I cut off `$_.DirectoryName` then I get the following output.

```
Directory: C:\TestProfileClean\username.V2\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\users\username%40compcorp%2Ecom


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       12/14/2016   9:56 AM                logs
```

Which will delete what I want but isn't specific enough for me to be comfortable running it.

What am doing wrong that is preventing folders from being deleted but the script will delete all non folder items.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the wildcard to go through all of them under the folder . I just modified your code :

```
Get-ChildItem 'F:\View\Profiles\*' -Recurse -Force |
    Where-Object {$_.Directory -match 'F:\\View\\Profiles\\((\w*).V2)\\AppData\\Roaming\\Trillian\\users\\((\w*%\w*%\w*))\\logs\\(_CLOUD|ASTRA)'} |
    Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Note: I am not checking the Regex. I am only tweaking the *get-childitem* part.

Apart from this , I have 2 other suggestion for you. If you really want to delete the user profiles nightly basis, then you can use the small utility tools

1) made of batch

2) made of powershell.

Below are the links for your reference.

[Delprof - Batch](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/)

[Delprof - Powershell](http://www.theinfraguy.com/2011/11/powershell-delprof-user-profile.html)

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: I am pretty sure the use of -Recurse negates the need for that, in any case doing that still only removes the files not the folders.

Currently the script still deletes files down as many folders as I want, but still leaves empty folders all over the place.

Comment: Are there any duplicates? Remove-Item holds the signature `protected override void RemoveItem(string path, bool recurse)`

Comment: Well, there are 170k files and folders I am trying to clean up. The file get cleaned up fine but the folders do not. Every folder in each profile is named the same but each profile has its own path.

Comment: Actually I created test folder. Under that I have test1 and test2 . Under test2 , I have test3 . When I use the same command, it worked .I will still try

Comment: I have attached the screenshots as a second answer.It is working fine. Requesting you to share the screenshots for the same

Comment: Try using windows native commands also: `for /r %R in (.svn) do if exist %R (rd /s /q "%R")`

Comment: Here is what happens when I run my code. Please try adding Where-Object statements to your code.

Comment: C:\Windows\system32> \\company.com\file share\IT\Infrastructure\Documentation\Network Admin\Admin Scripts\Admin\Delete Log Files Trillian File Server\Delete Trillian Log Files from Profiles.ps1
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "F:\View\Profiles\user.V2\AppData\Roaming\Trillian\users\user%40company%2Ecom\logs\ASTRA\Query\user@asrcorp.com.index".

Comment: Let me create the same folder structure and will try with regex.